# Why is my reference to jQuery not working inside of a JS file that calls on the processingJS library?

Tags: jquery, processing.js

I have this code:

```
var keys = [];
        function keyAction () {
    if (keys[38]) { //this checks if up arrow is pressed
        Player.yv = Player.yv - 1;
    }
    if (keys[40]) {
        Player.yv = Player.yv + 1;
    }
    if (keys[37]) {
        Player.xv = Player.xv - 1;
    }
    if (keys[39]) {
        Player.xv = Player.xv + 1;
    }
}

var Player = {
xv: 0,
yv: 0,
xpos: 200,
ypos: 200,
}

function movement () {
    Player.xpos = Player.xpos + Player.xv; //setting the positions to the positions + movement
    Player.ypos = Player.ypos + Player.yv;
    Player.xv = Player.xv * 0.9; //slowing it down
    Player.yv = Player.yv * 0.9;
}

function processingCode(processing) {

function drawPlayer () {
    processing.fill(255, 255, 255);
    processing.ellipse(Player.xpos, Player.ypos, 30, 30); //moves the circle
    keyAction();
    movement();

}

//Draw function--objects make it possible to add other players in the future
processing.draw = function() {
    processing.background(0, 0, 0); //Background
    drawPlayer();
}
}

$(document).ready(function() {
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var processingInstance = new Processing(canvas, processingCode);

$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    keys[e.which] = true;
    keyAction();
});

$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    delete keys[e.which];
    keyAction();
});
});
```

However, when I run it I get an error that says: "Can't find variable: $”. Why is this? I can get my canvas to work in pure processing code already and then compile it, but I’m trying to move over to all Javascript and jQuery so I can call events such as touch events. I loaded jQuery with the following:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: How are you referencing jQuery?

Comment: How exactly are you running this code? How exactly are you loading JQuery? Can you please post a [mcve] and/or link to a page running your code?

Comment: Check if this line: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script> located on the page before you JS code.

Comment: Thank you so much; I linked jQuery below my JS code.